# Trying to load up combo box values once (at login screen) vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a few combo boxes that need to be loaded up once and displayed multiple times (whenever the main form is opened) The reason for this is because it's taking about 10 seconds for the form to load each time it's opened due to unnecessary re-querying.

Here is an example of what I have as a combo box source and what I've done.

I've put the query, connection, etc... in a module and call it on the login form - i don't get any errors but the data does not load into the combos.

```
'In Module
sql = "SELECT DIR_ID, DIR_NM FROM LTC_FBS_DIR ORDER BY DIR_NM ASC"
RConStr = String.Format(RConStrFormat, LoginForm.txtUser.Text, LoginForm.txtPass.Text)
'using instead of dim connemp
Dim connemp4 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(RConStr)
connemp4.Open()
Dim datemp4 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connemp4)
datemp4.Fill(ds, "Dir")


'Form Load event

Dim tbl4 As DataTable = ds.Tables("Dir")
DBS_DIRECTORComboBox.DisplayMember = "DIR_NM"
DBS_DIRECTORComboBox.ValueMember = "DIR_ID"
DBS_DIRECTORComboBox.DataSource = tbl4
```

Comment: Are the items loading one and not on other controls, or not at all on any controls?  Where does the form get its reference to `ds` and where is the module called?

Comment: Which Windows Forms or Web Forms? Are you talking about asp.net?

Comment: windows forms, I'm calling the module on the login form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine; Make sure there is some data in dataset and/or Try skipping table mappings, I mean change your code lines.

**Replace this line**

```
datemp4.Fill(ds, "Dir")
```

**With this line**

```
datemp4.Fill(ds)
```

**Also replace this line**

```
//' in Form Load event
Dim tbl4 As DataTable = ds.Tables("Dir")
```

**With this one**

```
Dim tbl4 As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: I've tried the suggested and it's returning a series of "System.Data.DataRowView" rows in the combo box now... seems like it's doing more, but still not working.

Comment: oops I meant to replace only the two lines, but your comment says you did more than that.

Comment: No that's what i did... But i'm getting multiple rows of the system.data.dataroview messages in the corrosponding combo box.